# How does Wall of Roots interact with +1/+1 counters?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Wall of Roots](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWall%20of%20Roots%5d) puts a "-0/-1" counter on itself to use its ability. How does this interact with a +1/+1 counter? Do they cancel out to make a +1/+0 counter? Does they cancel out the same as a +1/+1 and -1/-1 counter and both counters cease to exist? Or do they both ignore each other completely?

Comment: Note that [about 36 cards in MTG's history](https://tagger.scryfall.com/tags/card/deprecated-p-t-counter) used power/toughness counters that weren't +1/+1 or -1/-1, and the concept has since been deprecated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They ignore each other completely, so the Wall of Roots will have both a -0/-1 counter and a +1/+1 counter (which has the net effect of having +1/+0).

The only reason +1/+1 and -1/-1 counters interact with each other is because of this state-based action:

> 704.5q If a permanent has both a +1/+1 counter and a -1/-1 counter on it, N +1/+1 and N -1/-1 counters are removed from it, where N is the smaller of the number of +1/+1 and -1/-1 counters on it.

There is no similar rule for -0/-1 counters.

Answer (score 8):

The only two power/toughness modifier counters which explicitly annihilate each other are +1/+1 and -1/-1 counters:

> 122.3. If a permanent has both a +1/+1 counter and a -1/-1 counter on it, N +1/+1 and N -1/-1 counters are removed from it as a state-based action, where N is the smaller of the number of +1/+1 and -1/-1 counters on it. See rule 704.

Other counters ignore each other and contribute to the power/toughness of the creature as they would do without each other. A Wall of Roots with one -0/-1 counter and one +1/+1 has power/toughness 1/5.